# Convert String to array

Tags: trigger, array

I have a string ex.(a,b,c) which is inputted in a textarea(long). how can I convert it into array in apex trigger? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need split the string with `,` that will return you list of string

Comment: String ourString = 'Salesforce SE';
String[] stringCharacters = ourString.split(,);
System.debug(stringCharacters); is it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the string using comma `,` that will return list.

```
String str = 'a,b,c';
List<String> lstString = str.split(',');
system.debug('---list of string---'+lstString );
```

Comment: will it work using words like String str = 'an apple a day, keeps the doctor, away'?

Comment: @gelay it will split the `an apple a day` this `keeps the doctor` and `away` .. it will add 3 string in the list

Comment: is there a .contains in apex trigger?

Comment: I didn't get you @gelay

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41488/discussion-between-gelay-and-ratan).